# Run command line code on button click

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jbutton, processbuilder

I'm working on a Java program and I want to execute some command line code when the user clicks a button. I have to code to execute my command line code and the button code but I don't now how to combine both:
My button code looks like the following:

```
    private JButton setup;
public ProgramGUI(){
    UsedHandler handler = new UsedHandler();
    setup.addActionListener(handler);

}
private class UsedHandler implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource()==setup)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Everything fine!");
    }
}
```

And that's my command line code:

```
            try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
            Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\helloworld.exe");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your exec code in a method and call it from inside the action performed from your button

```
public void yourProcess() {
try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
        Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\helloworld.exe");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and then use the method

```
 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource()==setup){
        yourProcess();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Everything fine!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the command line code takes a lot of time and block AWT, you need multi-threading.

```
private class UsedHandler implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private JButton setup;
    private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == setup) {
            executor.execute(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\helloworld.exe");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```